# Property 'then' does not exist on type 'RelayObservable<unknown>'. when I try to fetch data using relay in react. I don't know why this error come

Tags: javascript, reactjs, relayjs, relay, react-relay

Property 'then' does not exist on type 'RelayObservable'. when I try to fetch data using a relay in react.

```
  try {
            
            fetchQuery(environment, expenseQueryMyQuery,{}).then((data)=>{
                console.log("All data:::",data);
            }).catch((error)=>{
                console.log("query error::",error);
            })
           } catch (error) {
               
       }
```

Answer (score 2):

If this really is an Observable, you should use `.subscribe` more than `.then` (which is intended for Promises)

```js
fetchQuery(environment, expenseQueryMyQuery,{}).subscribe({
  next: (data)=>{
    console.log("All data:::",data);
  },
  error: (error)=>{
    console.log("query error::",error);
  }
})
```

Here's a link to the documentation for `fetchQuery` on the official website : https://relay.dev/docs/api-reference/fetch-query/#internaldocs-banner